# How to prove that a surface whose normal lines intersect a given line is a portion of a surface of revolution

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

I'm stuck on Exercise 3.70 from Kristopher Tapp's *Differential Topology of Curves and Surfaces*:

> Let $S$ be a connected oriented regular surface. Suppose there exists a line $L \subset \mathbb R^3$ that intersects all normal lines to $S$ (that is, for every $p \in S$, the trace of the normal line $t \mapsto p + t N(p)$ intersects $L$). Prove that $S$ is a portion of a surface of revolution.

I was able to show that every point $p \in S$ has a neighbourhood in $S$ whose intersection with the plane perpendicular to $L$ through $p$ is a circle with centre on $L$ (with the help of part (i) in this question: [How to solve this questions about regular surfaces?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1072187/how-to-solve-this-questions-about-regular-surfaces)):

> Note that we further require $L$ not to intersect $S$. First, suppose $L$ is the $z$-axis and let $p = (p_1, p_2, p_3) \in S$. Then $p + s N(p) = (0, 0, z)$ for some $s \in \mathbb R - \{0\}$ and some $z \in \mathbb R$, so $N(p) = (-p_1 / s, -p_2 / s, (z - p_3) / s)$. Note that $\langle(-p_1 / s, -p_2 / s, 0), N(p)\rangle = (p_1^2 + p_2^2) / s^2 \neq 0$, so $(-p_1 / s, -p_2 / s, 0) \notin T_pS$. Thus, either $e_1 \notin T_pS$ or $e_2 \notin T_pS$, and so by Exercise 3.48, there is a neighbourhood $V$ of $p$ in $S$ that is the graph of a smooth function of one of the following forms: $x = f(y, z)$, or $y = f(x, z)$, respectively. Define the curve $\gamma: I \to V$ by $\gamma(t) = (f(t, p_3), t, p_3)$ or $\gamma(t) = (t, f(t, p_3), p_3)$, respectively. Then $\gamma'(t) = (df_{(t, p_3)}(1, 0), 1, 0) \neq 0$ or $\gamma'(t) = (1, df_{(t, p_3)}(1, 0), 0) \neq 0$, and $\gamma(I) \subset p + \operatorname{span}\{e_1, e_2\}$. Conversely, if $(x, y, p_3) \in V$, then $x = f(y, p_3)$ or $y = f(x, p_3)$, and so $V \cap (p + \operatorname{span}\{e_1, e_2\}) \subset \gamma(I)$. We claim $\gamma$ is a portion of the circle centred at $(0, 0, p_3)$ through $p$. For each $t \in I$, let $\mathfrak n(t)$ denote the projection of $N(\gamma(t))$ onto $\operatorname{span}\{e_1, e_2\}$. Then
> $$\langle\mathfrak n(t), \gamma'(t)\rangle = \langle N(\gamma(t)), \gamma'(t)\rangle - \langle N(\gamma(t)), e_3\rangle \langle e_3, \gamma'(t)\rangle = 0$$
> and $\gamma(t) - (0, 0, p_3) = -\frac{\lvert\gamma(t) - (0, 0, p_3)\rvert}{\lvert\mathfrak n(t)\rvert} \mathfrak n(t)$ for all $t \in I$. Thus,
> $$\frac{d}{dt}\langle\gamma(t) - (0, 0, p_3), \gamma(t) - (0, 0, p_3)\rangle = -\frac{2 \lvert\gamma(t) - (0, 0, p_3)\rvert}{\lvert\mathfrak n(t)\rvert} \langle\gamma'(t), \mathfrak n(t)\rangle = 0,$$
> and so $\lvert\gamma(t) - (0, 0, p_3)\rvert$ is constant.

What I'm having trouble showing is that there's a *single* curve whose surface of revolution about the line $L$ contains $S$, i.e. that if two points of the surface are in the same plane perpendicular to $L$, then they're at the same distance from $L$ (the question [Surfaces of revolution - Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248209/surfaces-of-revolution-problem) does not address this); I'm pretty sure I need to use the fact that $S$ is connected, and hence path connected (I'm pretty sure I can show it is in fact smoothly path connected, if needed), but I can't seem to use a path between two points to obtain the single curve I need.

Given two points $p = (p_1, p_2, p_3), q = (q_1, q_2, q_3) \in S$ with $p_3 = q_3$ (still assuming $L$ is the $z$-axis), I believe I want to show that $p_1^2 + p_2^2 = q_1^2 + q_2^2$, or perhaps find a way to write $p_1^2 + p_2^2$ as a function of $p_3$. I've tried using the fact that there are *functions* $s: S \to \mathbb R - \{0\}, z: S \to \mathbb R$ such that $p + s(p) N(p) = (0, 0, z(p))$ and manipulating this equation to do the latter, and I've tried introducing a path (or curve, if needed) $\beta: [0, 1] \to S$ from $p$ to $q$ and using the fact that $\beta'(t) \in T_{\beta(t)}S$ to do the former, but haven't found anything that I can tell is useful.

Another thing I've thought to try after the discussion in the comments is to show that if there are points $p = (p_1, p_2, p_3), q = (q_1, q_2, q_3) \in S$ with $p_3 = q_3$ at different distances from the $z$-axis, then there is a point $\beta(t)$ on the curve from $p$ to $q$ (which would need to be regular, which I think I could guarantee by taking a piecewise-regular path and rounding off the corners in a neighbourhood thereof) with $\beta'(t)$ horizontal such that $T_{\beta(t)}S$ is horizontal, but I don't really see how to show this. By the first part of the proof, I know that one basis vector in $T_{\beta(t)}S$ is the tangent vector to the horizontal circle through $\beta(t)$, and presumably I need to somehow use the fact that $p, q$ are at different distances from the $z$-axis to show that $\beta'(t)$ is linearly independent of that vector, but I don't see how.

Comment: Please elaborate on your proof. How are you coming up with a curve, specifically?

Comment: @TedShifrin does that help?

Comment: I would try a more direct approach. Because every normal line intersects the $z$-axis, there can be no horizontal tangent plane and hence no point on your profile curve where the tangent line is horizontal. This tells you that each horizontal plane intersects the curve at most once. Another comment: You can get the profile curve by intersecting with a *single* plane containing the $z$-axis.

Comment: @TedShifrin could you explain how to get the curve you mention *globally*? I can only manage to get the result locally. I imagine with your approach that this is where connectedness comes in.

Comment: Did you try my final comment? Fix a vertical half-plane and intersect. Of course, a surface of revolution can certainly be disconnected, but if the profile curve has two components in a *half-plane*, then the surface will be disconnected. I think your path idea has great merit — just "project" that path into the vertical half-plane and it gives you the path you're wanting.

Comment: @TedShifrin The only result I'm familiar with about surfaces being intersected with planes is that each point has a *neighborhood* in the surface whose intersection with the plane is the trace of a curve. I do not see how this is sufficient to show that there cannot be two points in the surface with the same $z$-coordinate at different distances from the $z$-axis. As for the "projection", I don't see how to show that the union of the traces of the projections of the paths for each pair of points is the trace of a single curve.

Comment: To add, as far as I can tell, I cannot a priori say that the *projection* can't have horizontal tangent, because the path between two points might have a horizontal tangent.

Comment: What I can show, though, is that if the path has horizontal tangent, then the projection's tangent vector is zero.

Comment: Maybe my use of the word projection is confusing. If we take any vertical half-plane, we get the same profile curve. I just meant to follow whatever path you have on the surface *in* a single vertical half-plane (say $y\ge 0$ in the $xz$-plane).

Comment: @TedShifrin But how do you *show* that you get the same profile curve; that's my question.

Comment: You mean to ask why the profile curve is connected. It appears the same in every half-plane. If it is disconnected, so is the surface.

Comment: @TedShifrin I don't appreciate being told what I mean; I very much meant what I said.